# Expandable div overlap some other divs

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a expandable menu which should get on top of one div and push some other divs down.

[A mockup of what I am trying to do:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3NuU.jpg)
[image]

[And a concept Plunker:](http://plnkr.co/edit/HK62NEd8m1Ad5uxdVtCW?p=preview)

Comment: `.panelcollapse{position: fixed;width: 245px;background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);z-index: 100;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using Bootstrap and in order to achieve your desired behaviour you should  "extract" TITLE div from document flow, for example using "position:absolute" and then move it to accomodate to deisred position. 
Don't forget that you must extend it more than 100% in width... and push on the left with negative left position.

Comment: Cool, your solution would be something like this?
http://plnkr.co/edit/HK62NEd8m1Ad5uxdVtCW?p=preview
Is there a way to give the images (green boxes) padding relative to the heading div?

Comment: Yes, something like this. Don't forget to apply "minor fixes" to position and total width, in order to align both sides of this blue bar to other elements, and add a margin top to first element that must pushed down, or better.... a margin-bottom to the upper one (the expandable one)